# ClassNotFoundException Package Name, Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, package, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to send an object from my android phone to my pc with sockets and ObjectOutputStreams.
I have a object "Network" which I am trying to send. 
The two classes are identical on bot android and pc, except for the package thing. On my pc, I dont have a package name (I don't need to?) and on the Android I have a package name (Which I can't delete without errors).
So I guess I get the error because the program on the pc cant find the class/object because the package name is invalid.
So, how do I solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The two classes are identical on bot android and pc, except for the package thing.

So they're not identical.

> On my pc, I dont have a package name (I don't need to?)

You need the same package name at both ends.

> and on the Android I have a package name (Which I can't delete without errors). So I guess I get the error because the program on the pc cant find the class/object because the package name is invalid.

Correct.

> So, how do I solve this?

Use the same class with the same package name at both ends.